# Elasticsearch: Add field on the fly like driving distance by a user searching

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-rails

Is there a way to dynamically append a driving distance of the CONSUMER in ES?

I am trying to create an app and sort PROVIDERS by driving distance.

One thing I could think of is get all the PROVIDERS within a range then put them in an array. Iterate to add driving distance then sort array. But this is not efficient.

Any suggestions?

thank you!

Comment: can you plese add some sample document, sample query which you have tried and sample response you are expecting ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `runtime fields` to achieve what you want, A runtime field is a field that is evaluated at query time. Runtime fields enable you to:

- Add fields to existing documents without reindexing your data Start
- working with your data without understanding how it’s structured
- Override the value returned from an indexed field at query time
- Define fields for a specific use without modifying the underlying
  schema

For more information you can check Elasticsearch blog post [here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/introducing-elasticsearch-runtime-fields), and for runtime fields [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/runtime.html).